# Ramda, counting value frequency in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ramda.js

I have the following simple array

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

How can Ramda help me in achieving the following

```
{a: 4, b: 1, c: 2, d: 1}
```

`a:4` represents that value `a` exists `4` times in the main array

`b:1` represents that value `b` exists `1` time in the main array

`c:2` represents that value `c` exists `2` times in the main array

`d:1` represents that value `d` exists `1` time in the main array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`R.countBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy) with [`R.identity`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#identity) as the function that generates the keys:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a']

const result = R.countBy(R.identity, data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: ... and to understand why you need the `identity`, `countBy` might also be used for word length with `R.countBy(R.length, ['cat', 'chicken', 'cow', 'dog', 'goat', 'horse', 'pig', 'sheep']) //=> {"3": 4, "4": 1, "5": 2, "7": 1}` or used to count by any function, such as `R.countBy(R.prop('x'), [{x: 'yes', y: 42}, {x: 'no', y: 21}, {x: 'yes', y: 100}]) //=> {no: 1, yes: 2}`